# Encode audio file and make sure the packet duration is consistent

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a mp4 audio file, the packet/frame duration for all the packets is < 0.024 except of one packet, the duration is > 100s. I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` to re-encode the file and split that long packet into smaller packets but failed. it seems the duration is always the same as the source file

```
[FRAME]
media_type=audio
key_frame=1
pkt_duration_time=180.173469 s
nb_samples=1024
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=audio
key_frame=1
pkt_duration_time=0.023220 s
nb_samples=1024
[/FRAME]
```

I tried multiple commands but failed, one of the commands, for example:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile: a aac_low -b:a 192k -ar 48000 -ac 2 output.mp4`

I'm still new to the ffmpeg, I check the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), but could not find any option that can help me to accomplish this